# How to make second column be the largest but also able to shrink?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am new to CSS grid and trying to implement the second row only in the below picture.
I've tried to create six sections but have the second section spread out longer. For example I've tried:

```css
grid-column: 2 / span 5;
```

But it seems to push the last four section to the next line cause it to wrap which I do not want.

[image]

my unsuccessful code:

```css
.container {
  border: solid black 3px;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.item {
  border: solid skyblue 1px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  /* grid-column: 2 / span 5; */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">Totals</div>
  <div class="item">6000</div>
  <div class="item">-</div>
  <div class="item">194</div>
  <div class="item">12.5%</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `auto` on the columns, with `1fr` on the flexible one.

```css
.container {
  border: solid black 3px;
  height: 100px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(100px, auto) 1fr repeat(4, minmax(100px, auto));
}

.item {
  border: solid skyblue 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item">Totals</div>
  <div class="item">6000</div>
  <div class="item">-</div>
  <div class="item">194</div>
  <div class="item">12.5%</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qucy9Laf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `grid-auto-flow: column;` to your .container and change `grid-column: 2 / span 5;` to `grid-column: 2 / span 3;`